# Google Campaign Measurements Tracking

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I'm trying to setup the `Campaign Measurement` system to track where the users find my app. I've implemented the first part [Google Play Campaign Attribution](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#google-play-campaigns) [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#general-campaigns) but I can't seem to figure out how to do the [General Campaign & Traffic Source Attribution](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#general-campaigns) one.

It says that:

```
// In this example, campaign information is set using
// a url string with Google Analytics campaign parameters.
// Note: This is for illustrative purposes. In most cases campaign
//       information would come from an incoming Intent.
```

but I can't find any doc that specifies what would the name of the string received in the `Bundle`, or how exactly I should retrieve that url. I'm guessing it'll be sent to the app automatically, but I'm not 100% on how I must retrieve it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever any end-user clicked the ad on some social networking site or email, user will hit a url and this url will be sent to your application intent.

You can retrive this url via following code in your activity class:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Uri data = intent.getData();
```

and then you can send this data to GA for tracking using setCampaignParamsFromUrl() function.

Comment: I try this with Google Play Url Builder, but the content of intent.getData is null...

Comment: I  also tried this and the result is I am getting the data null even if in first open after publishing in google play store.